# Calling javascript href from mojolicious

Tags: javascript, html, user-agent, mojolicious

I've been given permission to scrape a website to build up a database of products. When a button is pressed, a javascript function is called and then altered information is presented to the user (change in colour, price etc..). When trying to scrape the website, I want to be able to predict the changes as if the button was pressed. The element in question is:

```
<a   id="anId" title="title" class="class" data-code="code" href="javascript:aFunction('ctl00$MainContent$ctl00$ctl00$FabricGroups$ctl00$FabricOptions$ctl00$FabricButton','')"></a>
```

Within mojolicious (I imagine the userAgent class?), how do I print the output of what calling the javascript function would do? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly isn't easy. Perl does not interpret javascript (at least not usually and almost certainly not with a DOM).

That said, I have been working on [a project](https://github.com/jberger/Mojo-Phantom) to help this, <s>WHICH IS DEFINITELY NOT READY FOR PRODUCTION</s>, which tests javascript actions by spawning an instance of [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). Once complete the api intends to be as easy to use as [Test::Mojo](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Test/Mojo) already is. I will be presenting it at [YAPC::NA](http://www.yapcna.org/yn2015/talk/6075) later in the year (2015).

Update: The module is now on CPAN, called [Test::Mojo::Role::Phantom](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Mojo::Role::Phantom).

Comment: Okay thanks Joel. Is it worth me playing around with PhantomJS in my Perl script now to see if i can mock something up that would solve the problem?

Comment: It does run, though it might be rough. If you using it for automated testing (the primary focus) then you will need one of the recent development releases of Test::Simple which include Test::Stream. My biggest claim is that I promise absolutely no stability at this point. Big things WILL still change.

Comment: Hi, have you got an update for this answer yet? How was the talk at YAPC::NA?

Comment: @Rambatino: Ah yes, it is available to use!